# Gantt Chart Controls on Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, controls, gantt-chart

We are evaluating options for a Gantt chart control (on Windows Forms) as opposed developing one on our own. What are the various Gantt Chart controls you have had experience with? Pros and cons?

Is it a viable idea to develop such a control from scratch (given that the control is not the primary product in this case)?

**Update:** Just bringing this up again since I've got only one answer. I'd be very grateful for more inputs. (Hope this is legal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with the Gantt charts from Telerik, but many people are very happy with Telerik.
I would never consider creating my own Gantt chart except if i was in the business of selling user controls

Answer (score 1):

Check out this company:

http://dlhsoft.com/Home.aspx

I have used their Gantt controls in both Winforms and WPF applications.

Colby Africa

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at the VARCHART XGantt control from NETRONIC. This control is around on the market for a long time, it is proven in mission critical applications, and very feature-rich. My answer is biased as I work for NETRONIC. I also openly share that we sell at higher prices than all tools mentioned above; and that is for a reason.

Have a look at our [Gantt chart](http://www.netronic.com/gantt/gantt-software.html/) offerings. If you like what you see, please send us an email to mailto:sales@netronic.com. Please refer to stackoverflow and ask that this email will get forwarded to Martin. He will get in contact to you to evaluate the potential of creating a complementary rapid prototype.

btw - A Gantt is typically more complex than many people assume. From talking to many of our clients (both software developers and end users) I know that using a proven control turns into tangible time-to-market benefits.

Does this help you although it is a vendor answer?

Answer (score 0):

FlexGantt at http://www.dlsc.com is a Java control but as far as I know you could port it to .NET with J++ or so. Then again, I am not an expert in that area.

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

Also, please note our very rich and interactive gantt control, natively written on both Silverlight and WPF:

http://www.radiantq.com

Thanks