# show timeslice with timeline in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to implement sjf (Scheduling) with c# and I need timeline for show how it workes. For example in this timeslice that process do its job. I want to show it graphically.

How I can do that?

Something like this :

[image]

i can implement, i just dont know how to show it graphically like that.it is windows form app in c#

Comment: 1. Be more specific. 2. Show us [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: 1: i need something like this:
http://ashotme.in/dsgdg.JPG
2: I have no idea.i tried nothing...and that's why I was asked.

Comment: Is it a Windows Form Application? Is it an Asp.Net application? Have you implement the algorithm and the only thing you want is to show it graphically? No one can help you if you don't give more information

Comment: yes i can implement, i just dont know how to show it graphically like that.
yes it is windows form app and c# application.

Answer (score 0):

To graphically display a schedule as you describe, using WinForms / C#, consider using a Gannt chart control.

Don't try building the control yourself, there are good off-the-shelf controls that are robust, low priced, well supported and have loads of sample code.

Telerik for example: http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chart.aspx

I mentioned Telerik as I've used their WinForms, WPF and ASP.Net controls before, they have plenty of different snippets of sample code, so it's easy to test out and they are well maintained with regular updates. Get a trial copy, see how it works for you and then go from there.

There are many others sources of Gannt controls, see previous StackOverflow topic: [Gantt Chart Controls on Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367570/gantt-chart-controls-on-windows-forms)